# Binary searching in an array

Tags: java, search, binary

This code searches for a number in an array by using the median. I have a problem with printing its position in the array. This code prints out the max value of the array. ex "234" "your number is on the the place 99999" "345" "your number is on the place 99998" and so on.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class sok2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int ListaLength = 100001; //Säger hur lång listan ska vara.
int [] array = new int[ListaLength];
for (int i = 0; i < ListaLength; i++) {
    array[i] = (int)(Math.random() * ((ListaLength - 1) + 1));
    Arrays.sort(array);
    System.out.println("Skriv in numret du letar efter.");
    int element = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt(); 

    boolean found = false;
    int min = 0;
    int max = array.length - 1;
    int median = max/2;

    while(! found && min <= max){
        if(array[median] == element){
            found = true;
        }
        if(array[median] < element){
            min = median + 1;
            median = (min + max) / 2;
        }
        else if(array[median] > element){
            max = median - 1;
            median = (max + min) / 2;
        }
    }
    // this is where i assume the problem is.
    System.out.println("Din siffra är på plats "+median);
}}}
```

Comment: Is not printing out anything or is it just not printing the correct value?

Comment: Its not printing the correct value. Its currently printing the max value of the array.

Comment: Yes. I have corrected your code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im sorry but i have noticed my mistake.

```
int ListaLength = 100001;
int [] array = new int[ListaLength];
for (int i = 0; i < ListaLength; i++) {
array[i] = (int)(Math.random() * ((ListaLength - 1) + 1));
 //there is supposed to be a closing bracket here.
Arrays.sort(array);
System.out.println("Skriv in numret du letar efter.");
int element = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically printing out median everytime your for loop executes, if you want the last position, save your median and print it out when the for loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code segment:

```
public static int bianarySearch(int[] array, int low, int high, int item) {
    int middle = (low + high) / 2;
    if (low > high) {
        return -1;
    } else if (array[mid] == item) {
        return middle;
    } else if (array[mid] < item) {
        return bianarySearch(array, item, middle + 1, high);
    } else {
        return bianarySearch(array, item, low, middle - 1);
    }
}
```